# Private Plugin Repository Using Satis

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Has anyone been successful using Satis for composer repo(s) with Craft plugins? I have a repo set up with artifacts, that are posted as a public composer repo in the network. It finds the plugins and downloads, but for some reason I keep getting the following error whenever I try to do `composer update`:

```
[craft\composer\InvalidPluginException]
  Couldn't install vendor/plugin: Unable to determine the base path
```

It works if I do a local path and pull it in that way.

Comment: Wow, the crickets sure are loud here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrestling with artifacts and that whole approach I simply created a private repo on github, then set up a local satis that pulls in from that repo and then serves it to the installs as a composer repository when running `composer update`. Works like a charm.